# Layout weight in Gridview

Tags: android

I want the cards to fill the entire screen when it comes to various screen dimensions. I would like to use the weights or any other option that can do the same.

```
        <!--Card 1-->
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cardView1"
            android:layout_height="200sp"
            android:layout_width="150sp">

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <!--Card 2-->
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cardView2"
            android:layout_height="200sp"
            android:layout_width="150sp">

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <!--Card 3-->
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cardView3"
            android:layout_height="200sp"
            android:layout_width="150sp">

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <!--Card 4-->
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cardView4"
            android:layout_height="200sp"
            android:layout_width="150sp">

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </GridLayout>
```

[image: I want the 4 cards to fit the entire screen for any device type]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="2">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

this might cause some performance problems on very old devices, but should not be a problem on the newer ones. 
Also, just add some margin around the cards to show the shadow if you want
hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to set the height of the gridview dynamically.
In your Activity class define.

```
     public static int heighth;
     public static int width;
     DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

        widthh = metrics.widthPixels;
        heighth = metrics.heightPixels;
```

And after this in your gridview adapter class write

```
gridView.setMinimumHeight((Home.heighth)/3-70);
```

Here Home is your Activity class `Home.java`. I have divided by 3 because I have only 3 rows and the subtraction of 70 is just for adjusting the view. Hope it helps!

Comment: This doesn't work for devices with on screen menu buttons like Galaxy S9 and so on. The display size would return the whole size of the screen.